# Is there a way to subscribe to a facebook page's public posts feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have seen the graph API for webhooks.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/

Here it says that I need the `manage_pages` permission from atleast one of the page admins, but I won't have access to this permission.

What I want to do is to stalk/crawl a facebook page's public posts or shared publicly by someone else on that page. I also want facebook to send me push notifications for these posts, all of this without having any permission from the page admins.

The other option for me is to poll the page's feed in the graph API, but I wanted to know if there was a better solution using callbacks.

Also, not looking for the public feed API. I doubt my use case will be given permission by facebook to use that API.

For the second option, mentioned above, I'm looking at this API -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed
But if I keep polling, I'll definitely see blocks around rate limiting.

Comment: No, there is no way to get webhook updates for a page you do not have admin access to. Notifications for new page posts you can get directly via the Facebook UI - although that is limited to 5 notifications per day. For everything else, you will have to poll /page-id/feed yourself.

Comment: Yeah.. unless I get access to the facebook public feed. Seems unlikely I'd get that though.